# How to write all decoded data in a JSON file?

Tags: json, xml, go

I try to parse an XML data to a JSON file, but when I begin writing marshaled data to a JSON, it just rewrites data in the JSON file and, as a result, I have the file with last XML element.  How to write the whole data into the JSON file?

Snippet of code that parses XML and marshal data to JSON

```golang
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(file)
    resultData := map[string]map[string]string{}
    for {
        t, _ := decoder.Token()
        if t == nil {
            break
        }

        switch et := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            if et.Name.Local == "profile" {
                var object XMLProfile
                decoder.DecodeElement(&object, &et)

                resultData = map[string]map[string]string{
                    object.ProfileName: {},
                }

                for _, val := range object.Fields {
                    resultData[object.ProfileName][val.Name] = val.Value
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if out, err := json.MarshalIndent(resultData, "", "\t"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        _ = ioutil.WriteFile("test.json", out, 0644)
    }
```

Expect JSON:

```
{
  "Profile 1": {
      "role": "user"
  },

  "Profile 2": {
      "role": "user"
  },

  "Profile 3": {
      "role": "admin"
  }
}
```

Actual JSON:

```
{
  "Profile 3": {
    "role": "admin"
  }
}
```

Comment: Write to the file once, after the loop, and not for each element.

Comment: @peter Same output. I think the problem is in resultData, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Vorsprung Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are recreating the resultData after each iteration in the nodes named "profile". As that happens, only the last one will reach the code where you write the JSON.

Try this:

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(file)
resultData := map[string]map[string]string{}
for {
    t, _ := decoder.Token()
    if t == nil {
        break
    }

    switch et := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        if et.Name.Local == "profile" {
            var object XMLProfile
            decoder.DecodeElement(&object, &et)

            resultData[object.ProfileName] = map[string]string{}

            for _, val := range object.Fields {
                resultData[object.ProfileName][val.Name] = val.Value
            }
        }
    }
}

if out, err := json.MarshalIndent(resultData, "", "\t"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile("test.json", out, 0644)
}
```

I would also check if no duplicate ProfileName happens to appear in the XML, as it would override the previous entry.